# OS X El Capitan downloaded form apple claims installation is successful, but new OS is not installed

Tags: macos, install

I have a compatible macbook pro (late 2008) for OS 10.11 and wish to upgrade from OS 10.8.5

The download was fine (6.2gb) and the installer began by saying 'will take 7mb of space'.  I ran the installer from my downloads folder anyway thinking there might be a mistake in the notification, but alas it hasn't installed the new OS (despite saying 'installation was succesful').

How can I see the log file when I run the installer to find out an error to fix?

Comment: Can you show a screenshot of where you downloaded from (what app, which url) and where you saved the installer? Or is that what’s holding you up, you need help locating the installer?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [OS X updater claims installation is successful, but new OS is not installed](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/381553/os-x-updater-claims-installation-is-successful-but-new-os-is-not-installed)